# MySQL - Update all columns on join between two tables with identical schemas

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with identical schemas, created as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
    pk INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ... other column definitions ...
    action CHAR(10) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE StageTable1 LIKE Table1;
```

The stage table is periodically cleared and loaded with some number of records. I want to update all columns of Table1 with matching values from StageTable1 for rows where action equals 'update'.

I understand how to do this in MySQL using UPDATE, INNER JOIN and SELECT.

```
UPDATE Table1 t
      INNER JOIN
      (
          SELECT *
          FROM StageTable1
          WHERE action = 'update'
      ) s ON t.pk = s.pk
SET t.action = s.action
    t.othercol1 = s.othercol2
    t.othercol2 = s.othercol2
    ...
```

But here's the catch. There are additional tables Table2, Table3, and so on that each have matching Stage tables. I want to generate the update query programatically and just change the table names and join column. I don't want to have to specify all the other column names which are different for each table pairing.

Is there a way in MySQL to take advantage of the fact that two tables have identical schemas to perform the update without having to specify each and every column?

I can of course query the column names (via SHOW COLUMNS) and build the SET part of the UPDATE query from those results but I'm trying to avoid having to do this.

I can also perform a DELETE FROM followed by an INSERT INTO but this is generally slower and frowned upon compared to doing an UPDATE. I would hate to have to pick this option just to avoid the column specification requirement.

Comment: DELETE/INSERT is not necessarily slower than UPDATE.

Comment: I don't think there is anything that will let you do the SETs you want in a MySQL query, short of using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` (or `SHOW COLUMNS` as you already mentioned) and building the query. You could do that in a Stored Procedure to construct and execute a `PREPARE`d statement though.